# Elements above the table

Tags: html, css, layout

I need to put some div's above the table (tasks in timetable). When I do `position: absolute` for them, task doesn't scroll with timetable. So, what should I do?

```
        .overlay {
            width: 8vw;
            height: 100px;
            position:absolute;
            z-index: 20
        }

<table>
<tr><td>5:00</td><td>_</td><tr>
<tr><td>6:00</td><td>_</td><tr>
<tr><td>7:00</td><td><div class="overlay">Task1</div></td><tr>
<tr><td>8:00</td><td>_</td><tr>
<tr><td>9:00</td><td>_</td><tr>
<tr><td>10:00</td><td>_</td><tr>
<tr><td>11:00</td><td>_</td><tr>
</table>
e.t.c.
```

Also, I should notice that the task can be longer, than one cell.
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRTLB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone like this my friend ?  a send you the codepen, for this type of tasks you need to use plugins like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-calendar   ,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-calendar

I created a parent `.parent  { position: relative }`

https://codepen.io/r0binxp/pen/mdPVzLX

Comment: The height then you should define it according to the duration of the task, and doing some calculations in number of pixels or percentage